# Migrating to vtk6: Is it not necessary to Update() (anymore)?

Tags: c++, vtk

Migrating some code from [VTK](https://vtk.org) 5.10 to 6.1, I have several code pieces like this:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> img = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
// ... initialize img somehow, e.g. copy from other image:
img->DeepCopy(otherImg);
img->SetInformation(otherImg->getInformation());
// the problematical statement:
img->Update();
```

At the call to `Update()`, the compiler now complains that there isn't such a function (anymore).
The migration site from VTK doesn't really tell me too much about that - I believe this falls into the section [Removal of Data Objects’ Dependency on the Pipeline](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Overview#Removal_of_Data_Objects.E2.80.99_Dependency_on_the_Pipeline) , but as it's no Algorithm which is filling my image, I can't call update on an algorithm.

Similar goes for custom-filled `vtkPolyData` objects.

My question now is: Is the call to Update not necessary (anymore?), can I just remove it? Or by what would I need to replace it?

I have to say I'm relatively new to vtk, so if there's something fundamentally simple that I'm missing I'd be glad if you could point it out to me!

Comment: I have experience with VTK but, unfortunately, not with the latest version (the 6.x). However, I've founded this, that remands to the link provided by you...Do that examples help you?
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Removal_of_Update

Comment: thanks, but does not really help me (at least I don't see how at the moment). There's only examples for data objects being filled from a filter or an algorithm, but not ones like in my example, where there is no such filter or algorithm. but maybe those two examples given there support the assumption that calling `Update` in my case is really superfluous, as there is no linked filter/algorithm for which the Update of the data object would be the proxy for?

Comment: Ok, I thinked that it could be useful, at least, for other parts of your code (where you could use, as an example, the vtkPolyData objects you was talking about). Regarding your last question, I think it could worth a try...Even if I don't know much more than you on this, since I've never used VTK 6.x :-( Good luck, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently they already answered your question on VTK:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Removal_of_Update

Answer (score 5):

I think you've been meaning to call Modified() on your image rather than Update().

Comment: is it required to call `Modified()` in above case? or, put otherwise, is there a general rule when to call it, and when it is done automatically? Or do I always have to call it if I modify an image?

Comment: I usually only have to call it whenever I touch data directly (using GetScalarPointer and then changing values using the pointer). Most member functions should call Modified() for you if it is necessary I believe.